NAPS2.Wia - supporting Legal paper size when scanning
I have a Windows Forms application targeting .Net Framework 4.7.2. The function of application is to scan documents using document scanner (flatbed or feeder), display documents on the screen and save the result to PDF. Note that the stack of documents placed in the feeder may contain a mix of Letter and Legal sized pages.
I use NAPS2.Wia (https://github.com/cyanfish/naps2-wia) component for scanning. If I don't explicitly specify paper size everything works except when Legal size paper is put in the feeder it is treated as a Letter sized paper and bottom of the page is cutoff.
I did find a solution but it is a bit of kludge:
// executed always
int scanResolution = 300; // dpi, user selectable
documentSource.SetProperty(WiaPropertyId.IPS_XRES, scanResolution);
documentSource.SetProperty(WiaPropertyId.IPS_YRES, scanResolution);

Then if the paper source is a feeder I additionally execute this:
int LegalPaperHeight = 14; 
documentSource.SetProperty(WiaPropertyId.IPS_YEXTENT, LegalPaperHeight*scanResolution);

Is there a better way to achieve the same result (I don't really like specifying paper height like that)? Something like paperSize=Auto
